# ¿Como aplicar una expresión regular en java?

Tags: java, regex

Lo que quiero es que la expresión que ya tengo funcione correctamente

Aquí esta la expresión regular

```
^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$
```

Esta expresión debería restringir de la siguiente forma

- Al menos 8 caracteres
- Maximo 15 caracteres
- Una letra mayúscula
- Una letra minúscula
- un número

Mi código completo seria así:

```
Pattern patN = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$");     

Matcher matN = patN.matcher(nick);

if (nick.length()<8 || nick.isEmpty() || matN.find()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Nick esta Mal");
}
```

Las primeras dos condiciones del If las realiza sin  problemas pero cuando pongo el tamaño mayor a 8 caracteres sin dígitos numéricos ni mayúsculas o minúsculas no lo valida y me permite guardar.

Comment: Necesitas invocar el método `matches`.

Comment: Primero: deberias usar matches, no find. Segundo: esa expresion regular es fea, dificil de mantener, siempre hay que preferir 2 o 3 expresiones regulares sencillas (u otro test sin expresiones regulares) a 1 sola expresion dificil de entender. Tercero: a mí me anda.

Comment: @PaulVargas El método `matches`, así como `find`, son dos alternativas para comparar una expresión regular con un texto. Sólo se diferencian en que `matches` fuerza a que la expresión regular esté anclada al inicio y al final del texto. Sin embargo, al usar `^` y `$` está logrando el mismo efecto.

Comment: @leonbloy Mirá el comentario anterior (está bien que use `Matcher.find()`). Por otro lado, no veo ningún perjuicio en utilizar esta expresión regular. -Vamos! Ya es prácticamente famosa, y cualquier desarrollador con un poco de experiencia la conoce. En todo caso, es algo que con un simple comentario se aclara. Realmente, no considero que sea difícil de mantener en absoluto.

Comment: @Mariano Está usted completamente en lo cierto. Seguro yo estaba dormitando (o en un estado sin cafeína) cuando escribí ese comentario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La expresión regular está bien. Lo que está mal es la condición del `if`.

Cuando la expresión regular coincide con el texto, el nick está bien. Y es **cuando no coincide** que el nick estaría mal. Para solucionarlo, hay que negar el resultado: `if (!matN.find()) {`.

```
Pattern patN = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$");     

Matcher matN = patN.matcher(nick);

if (!matN.find()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Nick esta Mal");
}
```

- Nótese el signo de admiración que se agregó.
- Saqué las primeras 2 condiciones, ya que son comprobadas por la expresión regular, y eran innecesarias.